# Проблема с подключением базы данных PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Решил написать форум с использованием `PDO`.

Не пойму в чем проблема, выдает ошибку 500.

В отдельном файле все отлично работает, в основном файле нет.

- Файл request.php :

  [image: i.stack.imgur.com/BEdWW.png]
- Файл database.class.php :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Файл function.class.php :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нет.. Не могу понять в чем проблема уже несколько часов точно

Comment: А вы логи web-сервера смотрели ? при 500 ошибках их суть обычно остается в error_log ...

Comment: Ошибка: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /tmp/m_forum/function.class.php on line 28
foreach($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `umbrella_forum`") as $row)

Comment: @DimaRRR Вставьте код в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения.

Comment: ...и сообщение об ошибке тоже, это часть вопроса как-никак. В ошибке обычно содержится половина решения.

Answer (score 1):

В функции `getForums()`, что представлена на изображении, переменная `$pdo` не объявлена. По всей видимости это объект для работы с базой, который объявлен в глобальной области видимости. Но в `php` в теле функции не доступны глобальные переменные, пока они не объявлены явно:

```
$wow='wow'; //глобальная переменая
function sayWow(){
  global $wow; //теперь переменная доступна в теле функции
  echo $wow; 
}
```

[Область видимости переменной](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php)

В вашем случае, скорее всего, `getForums()` - метод какого-нибудь класса. Значит используем `$this`:

```
public function getForums(){
  /* ... */
  $this->pdo->query('SELECT * FROM forums');
  /* ... */
}
```

И не забываем внедрить `$pdo` в конструкторе или отдельном методе.

[Классы и объекты](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.php)